# how to create a table/column family with many number of columns in cassandra?

Tags: csv, cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have 10,000 columns and i have a csv file with a header,is it possible to create a columns by using this csv file header ?

```
create table usertable (
    y_id varchar primary key,
    field0 varchar,
    field1 varchar,
    field2 varchar,
     ...
     ...
    field9999 varchar,
    field10000 varchar);
```

I am very sure the above column family creation is not sufficient.I want to load all column names from that csv file header instead of writing manually

Comment: Automatic inferring of datatypes? Spark dataframes API lets you load it as dataframe and save it to Cassandra as table, but I'm not sure it uses the correct data types.

Comment: Sorry, As I can see it in the code fragment of yours if all of them are varchars then you can safely use Spark SQL to do this. Cassandra COPY command needs a table already present.

Comment: i don't want to write column names and data types manually,is their any automatic procedure to create a schema by using csv file header

Comment: Spark SQL as I mentioned above.